# A way to determine browser width in PHP without javascript?

Tags: php, browser-width

First off is there one? Or would I have to use javascript?
I'd like to be able to make changes to which CSS is used, so frex I could load smaller fonts for a mobile device, or whatever.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to do this. If you want to detect what device is being used then you should examine `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` for clues.

Answer (score 9):

Unfortunately there is no way to detect the users resolution with PHP only. If you use Javascript, you could set this value in a cookie, and all subsequent requests could check the value of that cookie. This seems to be a pretty popular method for those working with this issue.

You could also run a small javascript from the page that checks to see if a resolution-cookie is set. If it's not, it sends an asynchronous request to the server containing the screen resolution. The server determines which CSS file to use by this value, and sends its path back to the javascript. A cookie is then set to indicate resolution has been determined, and the css file is subsequently loaded (via javascript) into the page. All future requests would cease assuming they're contingent upon the resolution cookie.

Answer (score 6):

You can use **$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']** by using the following code:

**Code:**

```
//_______________DETECT DEVICES__________________//
$tablet_browser = 0;
$mobile_browser = 0;

if (preg_match('/(tablet|ipad|playbook)|(android(?!.*(mobi|opera mini)))/i', strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']))) {
    $tablet_browser++;
}

if (preg_match('/(up.browser|up.link|mmp|symbian|smartphone|midp|wap|phone|android|iemobile)/i', strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']))) {
    $mobile_browser++;
}

if ((strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT']),'application/vnd.wap.xhtml+xml') > 0) or ((isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_WAP_PROFILE']) or isset($_SERVER['HTTP_PROFILE'])))) {
    $mobile_browser++;
}

$mobile_ua = strtolower(substr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 0, 4));
$mobile_agents = array(
    'w3c ','acs-','alav','alca','amoi','audi','avan','benq','bird','blac',
    'blaz','brew','cell','cldc','cmd-','dang','doco','eric','hipt','inno',
    'ipaq','java','jigs','kddi','keji','leno','lg-c','lg-d','lg-g','lge-',
    'maui','maxo','midp','mits','mmef','mobi','mot-','moto','mwbp','nec-',
    'newt','noki','palm','pana','pant','phil','play','port','prox',
    'qwap','sage','sams','sany','sch-','sec-','send','seri','sgh-','shar',
    'sie-','siem','smal','smar','sony','sph-','symb','t-mo','teli','tim-',
    'tosh','tsm-','upg1','upsi','vk-v','voda','wap-','wapa','wapi','wapp',
    'wapr','webc','winw','winw','xda ','xda-');

if (in_array($mobile_ua,$mobile_agents)) {
    $mobile_browser++;
}

if (strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']),'opera mini') > 0) {
    $mobile_browser++;
    //Check for tablets on opera mini alternative headers
    $stock_ua = strtolower(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_OPERAMINI_PHONE_UA'])?$_SERVER['HTTP_X_OPERAMINI_PHONE_UA']:(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_DEVICE_STOCK_UA'])?$_SERVER['HTTP_DEVICE_STOCK_UA']:''));
    if (preg_match('/(tablet|ipad|playbook)|(android(?!.*mobile))/i', $stock_ua)) {
      $tablet_browser++;
    }
}

if ($tablet_browser > 0) {
   // do something for tablet devices
   print 'is tablet';
}
else if ($mobile_browser > 0) {
   // do something for mobile devices
   print 'is mobile';
}
else {
   // do something for everything else
   print 'is desktop';
}   
 //_______________END DETECTING DEVICES__________________//
```

**Output**

If tablet: `'is tablet'`

If mobile: `'is mobile'`

If desktop: `'is desktop'`

Answer (score 5):

Pure HTML and CSS trick to get the width of the display. This will get you within 10 pixels. It highlights in red down to the display width. The first black on white number should be the display width:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Dart Foods</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<STYLE type="text/css">
hr {background-color: red;border: 1px solid blue;}
@media (max-width: 1920px) {#d1920{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 1910px) {#d1910{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 1900px) {#d1900{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 1890px) {#d1890{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 1880px) {#d1880{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 1870px) {#d1870{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 1860px) {#d1860{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 1850px) {#d1850{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 1840px) {#d1840{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 1830px) {#d1830{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 1820px) {#d1820{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 1810px) {#d1810{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 1800px) {#d1800{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 1790px) {#d1790{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 1780px) {#d1780{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 1770px) {#d1770{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 1760px) {#d1760{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 1750px) {#d1750{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 1740px) {#d1740{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 1730px) {#d1730{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 1720px) {#d1720{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 1710px) {#d1710{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 1700px) {#d1700{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 1690px) {#d1690{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 1680px) {#d1680{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 1670px) {#d1670{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 1660px) {#d1660{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 1650px) {#d1650{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 1640px) {#d1640{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 1630px) {#d1630{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 1620px) {#d1620{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 1610px) {#d1610{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 1600px) {#d1600{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 1590px) {#d1590{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 1580px) {#d1580{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 1570px) {#d1570{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 1560px) {#d1560{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 1550px) {#d1550{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 1540px) {#d1540{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 1530px) {#d1530{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 1520px) {#d1520{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 1510px) {#d1510{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 1500px) {#d1500{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 1490px) {#d1490{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 1480px) {#d1480{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 1470px) {#d1470{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 1460px) {#d1460{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 1450px) {#d1450{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 1440px) {#d1440{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 1430px) {#d1430{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 1420px) {#d1420{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 1410px) {#d1410{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 1400px) {#d1400{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 1390px) {#d1390{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 1380px) {#d1380{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 1370px) {#d1370{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 1360px) {#d1360{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 1350px) {#d1350{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 1340px) {#d1340{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 1330px) {#d1330{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 1320px) {#d1320{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 1310px) {#d1310{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 1300px) {#d1300{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 1290px) {#d1290{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 1280px) {#d1280{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 1270px) {#d1270{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 1260px) {#d1260{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 1250px) {#d1250{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 1240px) {#d1240{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 1230px) {#d1230{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 1220px) {#d1220{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 1210px) {#d1210{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 1200px) {#d1200{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 1190px) {#d1190{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 1180px) {#d1180{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 1170px) {#d1170{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 1160px) {#d1160{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 1150px) {#d1150{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 1140px) {#d1140{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 1130px) {#d1130{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 1120px) {#d1120{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 1110px) {#d1110{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 1100px) {#d1100{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 1090px) {#d1090{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 1080px) {#d1080{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 1070px) {#d1070{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 1060px) {#d1060{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 1050px) {#d1050{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 1040px) {#d1040{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 1030px) {#d1030{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 1020px) {#d1020{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 1010px) {#d1010{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 1000px) {#d1000{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 990px) {#d990{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 980px) {#d980{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 970px) {#d970{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 960px) {#d960{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 950px) {#d950{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 940px) {#d940{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 930px) {#d930{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 920px) {#d920{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 910px) {#d910{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 900px) {#d900{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 890px) {#d890{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 880px) {#d880{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 870px) {#d870{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 860px) {#d860{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 850px) {#d850{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 840px) {#d840{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 830px) {#d830{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 820px) {#d820{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 810px) {#d810{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 800px) {#d800{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 790px) {#d790{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 780px) {#d780{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 770px) {#d770{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 760px) {#d760{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 750px) {#d750{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 740px) {#d740{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 730px) {#d730{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 720px) {#d720{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 710px) {#d710{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 700px) {#d700{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 690px) {#d690{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 680px) {#d680{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 670px) {#d670{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 660px) {#d660{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 650px) {#d650{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 640px) {#d640{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 630px) {#d630{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 620px) {#d620{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 610px) {#d610{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 600px) {#d600{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 590px) {#d590{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 580px) {#d580{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 570px) {#d570{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 560px) {#d560{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 550px) {#d550{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 540px) {#d540{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 530px) {#d530{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 520px) {#d520{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 510px) {#d510{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 500px) {#d500{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 490px) {#d490{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 480px) {#d480{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 470px) {#d470{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 460px) {#d460{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 450px) {#d450{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 440px) {#d440{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 430px) {#d430{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 420px) {#d420{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 410px) {#d410{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 400px) {#d400{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 390px) {#d390{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 380px) {#d380{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 370px) {#d370{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 360px) {#d360{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 350px) {#d350{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 340px) {#d340{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 330px) {#d330{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 320px) {#d320{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 310px) {#d310{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 300px) {#d300{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 290px) {#d290{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 280px) {#d280{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 270px) {#d270{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 260px) {#d260{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 250px) {#d250{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 240px) {#d240{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 230px) {#d230{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 220px) {#d220{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 210px) {#d210{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 200px) {#d200{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 190px) {#d190{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 180px) {#d180{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 170px) {#d170{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 160px) {#d160{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 150px) {#d150{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 140px) {#d140{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 130px) {#d130{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 120px) {#d120{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 110px) {#d110{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 100px) {#d100{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 90px) {#d90{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 80px) {#d80{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 70px) {#d70{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 60px) {#d60{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 50px) {#d50{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 40px) {#d40{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 30px) {#d30{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 20px) {#d20{background-color: red;}}
@media (max-width: 10px) {#d10{background-color: red;}}
</STYLE>
</head>
<body>
Your width is approximately:
<hr>
<div id="d1920" >1920</div>
<div id="d1910" >1910</div>
<div id="d1900" >1900</div>
<div id="d1890">1890</div>
<div id="d1880">1880</div>
<div id="d1870">1870</div>
<div id="d1860">1860</div>
<div id="d1850">1850</div>
<div id="d1840">1840</div>
<div id="d1830">1830</div>
<div id="d1820">1820</div>
<div id="d1810">1810</div>
<div id="d1800">1800</div>
<div id="d1790">1790</div>
<div id="d1780">1780</div>
<div id="d1770">1770</div>
<div id="d1760">1760</div>
<div id="d1750">1750</div>
<div id="d1740">1740</div>
<div id="d1730">1730</div>
<div id="d1720">1720</div>
<div id="d1710">1710</div>
<div id="d1700">1700</div>
<div id="d1690">1690</div>
<div id="d1680">1680</div>
<div id="d1670">1670</div>
<div id="d1660">1660</div>
<div id="d1650">1650</div>
<div id="d1640">1640</div>
<div id="d1630">1630</div>
<div id="d1620">1620</div>
<div id="d1610">1610</div>
<div id="d1600">1600</div>
<div id="d1590">1590</div>
<div id="d1580">1580</div>
<div id="d1570">1570</div>
<div id="d1560">1560</div>
<div id="d1550">1550</div>
<div id="d1540">1540</div>
<div id="d1530">1530</div>
<div id="d1520">1520</div>
<div id="d1510">1510</div>
<div id="d1500">1500</div>
<div id="d1490">1490</div>
<div id="d1480">1480</div>
<div id="d1470">1470</div>
<div id="d1460">1460</div>
<div id="d1450">1450</div>
<div id="d1440">1440</div>
<div id="d1430">1430</div>
<div id="d1420">1420</div>
<div id="d1410">1410</div>
<div id="d1400">1400</div>
<div id="d1390">1390</div>
<div id="d1380">1380</div>
<div id="d1370">1370</div>
<div id="d1360">1360</div>
<div id="d1350">1350</div>
<div id="d1340">1340</div>
<div id="d1330">1330</div>
<div id="d1320">1320</div>
<div id="d1310">1310</div>
<div id="d1300">1300</div>
<div id="d1290">1290</div>
<div id="d1280">1280</div>
<div id="d1270">1270</div>
<div id="d1260">1260</div>
<div id="d1250">1250</div>
<div id="d1240">1240</div>
<div id="d1230">1230</div>
<div id="d1220">1220</div>
<div id="d1210">1210</div>
<div id="d1200">1200</div>
<div id="d1190">1190</div>
<div id="d1180">1180</div>
<div id="d1170">1170</div>
<div id="d1160">1160</div>
<div id="d1150">1150</div>
<div id="d1140">1140</div>
<div id="d1130">1130</div>
<div id="d1120">1120</div>
<div id="d1110">1110</div>
<div id="d1100">1100</div>
<div id="d1090">1090</div>
<div id="d1080">1080</div>
<div id="d1070">1070</div>
<div id="d1060">1060</div>
<div id="d1050">1050</div>
<div id="d1040">1040</div>
<div id="d1030">1030</div>
<div id="d1020">1020</div>
<div id="d1010">1010</div>
<div id="d1000">1000</div>
<div id="d990">990</div>
<div id="d980">980</div>
<div id="d970">970</div>
<div id="d960">960</div>
<div id="d950">950</div>
<div id="d940">940</div>
<div id="d930">930</div>
<div id="d920">920</div>
<div id="d910">910</div>
<div id="d900">900</div>
<div id="d890">890</div>
<div id="d880">880</div>
<div id="d870">870</div>
<div id="d860">860</div>
<div id="d850">850</div>
<div id="d840">840</div>
<div id="d830">830</div>
<div id="d820">820</div>
<div id="d810">810</div>
<div id="d800">800</div>
<div id="d790">790</div>
<div id="d780">780</div>
<div id="d770">770</div>
<div id="d760">760</div>
<div id="d750">750</div>
<div id="d740">740</div>
<div id="d730">730</div>
<div id="d720">720</div>
<div id="d710">710</div>
<div id="d700">700</div>
<div id="d690">690</div>
<div id="d680">680</div>
<div id="d670">670</div>
<div id="d660">660</div>
<div id="d650">650</div>
<div id="d640">640</div>
<div id="d630">630</div>
<div id="d620">620</div>
<div id="d610">610</div>
<div id="d600">600</div>
<div id="d590">590</div>
<div id="d580">580</div>
<div id="d570">570</div>
<div id="d560">560</div>
<div id="d550">550</div>
<div id="d540">540</div>
<div id="d530">530</div>
<div id="d520">520</div>
<div id="d510">510</div>
<div id="d500">500</div>
<div id="d490">490</div>
<div id="d480">480</div>
<div id="d470">470</div>
<div id="d460">460</div>
<div id="d450">450</div>
<div id="d440">440</div>
<div id="d430">430</div>
<div id="d420">420</div>
<div id="d410">410</div>
<div id="d400">400</div>
<div id="d390">390</div>
<div id="d380">380</div>
<div id="d370">370</div>
<div id="d360">360</div>
<div id="d350">350</div>
<div id="d340">340</div>
<div id="d330">330</div>
<div id="d320">320</div>
<div id="d310">310</div>
<div id="d300">300</div>
<div id="d290">290</div>
<div id="d280">280</div>
<div id="d270">270</div>
<div id="d260">260</div>
<div id="d250">250</div>
<div id="d240">240</div>
<div id="d230">230</div>
<div id="d220">220</div>
<div id="d210">210</div>
<div id="d200">200</div>
<div id="d190">190</div>
<div id="d180">180</div>
<div id="d170">170</div>
<div id="d160">160</div>
<div id="d150">150</div>
<div id="d140">140</div>
<div id="d130">130</div>
<div id="d120">120</div>
<div id="d110">110</div>
<div id="d100">100</div>
<div id="d90">90</div>
<div id="d80">80</div>
<div id="d70">70</div>
<div id="d60">60</div>
<div id="d50">50</div>
<div id="d40">40</div>
<div id="d30">30</div>
<div id="d20">20</div>
<div id="d10">10</div>
<hr>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

This may be of some use if you don't want to use any JavaScript:

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html#media-types

Answer (score 3):

The best way to do it, is to use CSS with media types

Here I give you a example for what you want, i.e., it adapts the fonts size for many tags, and the divs[1,2,3] orientation (horizontal or vertical), depending on the browsers width

I use here 'p5' tag with a greater font than 'p4'

use it preferably within a css external style file

```
/*default size*/    
nobr{ white-space:nowrap; }

p5 {font-size:350%;}
p4 {font-size:95%;}

#container {width: 100%; display:block; overflow:auto; }

#div1{
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    text-align: center;
}

#div2{
    float: left;
    width: 60%;
    text-align: center;
    display:block; overflow:auto;
}

#div3{
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    text-align: center;
    display:block; overflow:auto;
}

/*when the browsers width is between 500 and 700 pixels*/   
@media screen and (max-width:700px)  and (min-width:500px){
    p5 {font-size:200%;}
    p4 {font-size:90%;}

    #container { width: 100%; display:block; overflow:auto; }
    #main_div {border:solid 2px black;padding:15px}

    #div1{
        float: none;
        width: auto;
        text-align: center;
    }

    #div2{
        float: none;
        width: auto;
        margin: 0;
        text-align: center;
        display:block; overflow:auto;
    }

    #div3{
        float: none;
        width: auto;
        margin: 0;
        text-align: center;
    }
}

/*when the browsers width is less than 500 pixels*/
@media screen and (max-width:500px){
    p5 {font-size:150%;}
    p4 {font-size:85%;}

    #main_div {border:none;padding:0px}
    #container { width: 100%; display:block; overflow:auto; }

    #div1{
        float: none;
        width: auto;
        text-align: center;
    }

    #div2{
        float: none;
        width: auto;
        margin: 0;
        text-align: center;
        display:block; overflow:auto;
    }

    #div3{
        float: none;
        width: auto;
        margin: 0;
        text-align: center;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should look at [Tera-WURFL](http://www.tera-wurfl.com), it is a PHP & MySQL-based software package that detects mobile devices and their capabilities.  Here is the Tera-WURFL code that you would use to detect the browser width in PHP:

```
<?php
require_once("TeraWurfl.php");
$wurflObj = new TeraWurfl();
$wurflObj->GetDeviceCapabilitiesFromAgent();
$browser_width = $wurflObj->capabilities['display']['max_image_width'];
// You can also get the actual display resolution
$display_width = $wurflObj->capabilities['display']['resolution_width'];
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution I have has actually worked real well for years now - no plugins, no classes. Basically, while outputting the HEAD part of the doc, I output some JavaScript that gets the browser width and writes  it to a cookie. Then, later, further down the page, I simply read the cookie that has the exact width stored using the $_COOKIE function in php. It has not failed me once in any scenario.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
     <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
       <script> 

        function setCookie(cname,cvalue,exdays) {
          var d = new Date();
          d.setTime(d.getTime()+(exdays*24*60*60*1000));
          var expires = "expires="+d.toGMTString();
          document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
        }

        function window_height() {
           if (document.body) {
             winH = document.body.offsetHeight;
           }

          if (document.compatMode=='CSS1Compat' &&
             document.documentElement &&
             document.documentElement.offsetHeight ) {
             winH = document.documentElement.offsetHeight;
             return winH
          }

         if (window.innerHeight && window.innerHeight) {
            winH = window.innerHeight;
            return winH;
         }
      }     

      function window_width() {
        if (document.body) {
          winW = document.body.offsetWidth;
        }

       if (document.compatMode=='CSS1Compat' &&
          document.documentElement &&
          document.documentElement.offsetWidth ) {
          winW = document.documentElement.offsetWidth;
          return winW
       }

       if (window.innerWidth && window.innerWidth) {
         winW = window.innerWidth;
         return winW;
       }
     }      
       /* Upon page load, get the page width and height, and store in a JSON object/Cookie */
       setTimeout(function(){
         setCookie('w_w',JSON.stringify({'width':window_width(),'height':window_height()}))
       })

     </script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <?
        /* .........your PHP code...........*/
        /* .........your PHP code...........*/
        /* Access precise window dimensions */
        $xy=json_decode($_COOKIE['w_w']);
        $width=$xy->width;
        $height=$xy->height;
      ?>
     </body>
   </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

About all you can do is detect the browser model. From there you could match for common mobile browsers (iPhones all stick iPhone into the useragent string) and load smaller fonts by default and adjust from there.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [WURFL](http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/).
As Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams suggested in his answer, it uses the user agent string to "guess" the resolution for known devices. If you're concerned about mobile devices that's probably as accurate as you can get without the help of a client-side script/app.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use JavaScript. The server knows nothing about highly client-side data like that. Fortunately, JavaScript can manipulate styles and style sheets quite easily, so it should be able to tackle your problem without even involving anything server-side.

In the case of mobile devices, another easy tool is setting the media type on a style sheet to handheld.

Comment: except javascript isn't supported on all browsers which is the entire point of his post. not to mention javascript is a mess. look at the new google+ .

Comment: Not saying it's ideal (when was anything in web development ideal?). Just trying to help make the best of bad options.